# add vcal in email through C#

Tags: c#, vcal

I have a requirement to add VCal option in the email send to a person through C#.
I have implemented the VCal function in my web application. 

My email body is also of type HTML. I want to add the same VCal option in my email content as well. 
Is there any way to achieve the same instead of adding the .ics file as an attachment?
I want to programtically add outlook reminder(.ics file) through email. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [aspnetEmail](http://aspnetemail.com/) for the $129 its probally a lot cheaper then writting it yourself. They are also fairly responsive with support questions.

This tool will give you all the functionality you need plus some.